# How do I set TreeController's Content Object when showing a NSXMLDocument in Outline View

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller, nsxmldocument

I would like to show a NSXMLDocument in Outline View. Thankfully apple has a document for that called "Using Tree Controllers With NSXML Objects".

But one thing I did not get is that how I set TreeController's Content Object.

Firstly I set "Bind to" to the NSXMLDocument I want to show and "Model Key Path" to its rootElement. But that won't work.

I find that I have to set "Bind to" to an object who has the NSXMLDocument as its property and set "Model Key Path" to the NSXMLDocument.rootElement.

So why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my first binding attempt did not succeed. Because with the binding like that my NSXMLDocument was created in IB, then I can't set its content actually. (I do not how I can do that)

With my second binding, I can call NSXMLDocument's initWithData method. So my NSXMLDocument gets its data correctly.

So my question became how can I (or is it possible) to set NSXMLDocument content if it is created with IB ? Because event with awakeFromNib method, I don't know how I can set its content. I tried to call setRootElement, but get's exception said that "Cannot add a child that has a parent; detach or copy first"